# Forecast API cost Azure

Tags: azure, api, forecast

I'm trying to get the Forecast cost of my Azure Subscription. To do this, I'm using what I found in this documentation: [Forecast - Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/forecast/usage).
I tried to use the TRY button in the documentation of Microsoft with this JSON:

```
{
  type: "Usage",
  dataset: {
    "granularity": "monthly",
    "aggregation":{
      "totalCost":{
        "name":"Cost",
        "function":"Sum"
      }
    }
  },
  timeframe: "MonthToDate"
}
```

and with this request:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fay0p.png)

and I get ERROR 400 with this response:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"BadRequest",
      "message":"Invalid query definition: Invalid dataset grouping: 'BillingPeriod'; valid values: 'ResourceGroup','ResourceGroupName','ResourceType','ResourceId','ResourceLocation','SubscriptionId','SubscriptionName','MeterCategory','MeterSubcategory','Meter','ServiceFamily','UnitOfMeasure','PartNumber','BillingAccountName','BillingProfileId','BillingProfileName','InvoiceSection','InvoiceSectionId','InvoiceSectionName','Product','ResourceGuid','ChargeType','ServiceName','ProductOrderId','ProductOrderName','PublisherType','ReservationId','ReservationName','Frequency','InvoiceId','PricingModel','CostAllocationRuleName','MarkupRuleName','BillingMonth','Provider','BenefitId','BenefitName','CustomerTenantId','CustomerTenantDomainName','ResellerMPNId','PartnerEarnedCreditApplied','CustomerName','PartnerName',''.\r\n\r\n (Request ID: 16022d38-1857-4be5-a8cd-1b488325aa9b)"
   }
}
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What value did you use in "Scope"? Can you update the question with what is present in Request Preview (after removing the Authorization details.

Comment: Hi, I added a photo with my request. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with MS support on this. I opened the case as the end on May 2022 and they finally got back to me on Aug 1st 2022. They gave me a modified request body:

```
 {
   type: "Usage",
   dataset: {
     "granularity": "monthly",
     "aggregation":{
       "totalCost":{
         "name":"Cost",
         "function":"Sum"
       }
     }
   },
   timeframe: "Custom",
   "timePeriod": {
     "from": "2022-08-01",
     "to": "2022-08-31"
   }
```

and it worked.

```
  $forecast = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $forecasturi -Method post -Headers $authHeader -body $body  
    
  $forecast.properties.rows
 430.2517981776787
 2022-08-01T00:00:00
 Forecast
 USD
```